# Error Wamp when launch : The procedure entry point zend_unmangle_property_name_ex could not be located in te dynamic link library

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I have a problem when i launch WampServer, the error : The procedure entry point zend_unmangle_property_name_ex could not be located in the dynamic link library `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.5\ext\php_soap.dll`

Wamp can run after this warning, but i need php_soap.dll to install the plug-in WebService.

In the **php.ini**, **php_soap.dll** are uncommented and it is in the `extension_dir = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/ext/"` like indicated in the php.ini

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 `php.ini` files

Us the wampmanager icon like this to edit the correct `php.ini` file

```
left click wampmanager -> PHP -> PHP Extensions -> php_soap
```

If the menu item `php_soap` is not ticked, then click it and it will enable `php_soap` and restart Apache to pick upi the change